# Where is `CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE` in OpenCV 3.1.0 with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, opencv

I get this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE'
```

After upgrading my OpenCV to 3.1.0.
I have tried these.

```
cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
```

And also this.

```
cv2.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
```

But still same error. I go here, http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d31/group__objdetect__c.html#ga812f46d031349fa2ee78a5e7240f5016 but I could not find any information of to which object the constants stored in.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The sub module `cv` has been removed from `opencv 3.0`,

You can use an alternative `cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE`

**[Edit]**

For further details check [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I can see the change logs or documentations for Python?

Comment: Gone through this, http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dfa/tutorial_transition_guide.html